# Windows XP Embedded StandBy & Hibernate

Tags: thin-client, windows-embedded

Does Windows XP Embedded support StandBy & Hibernate when used as a thin client?

If so what happens to the server remote/virtual desktop connection on resume - is it automatically restored?

I'm trying to understand how Windows works as a thin client as I have a client who is trying to run my software on such a machine and its not working. Unfortunately I don't have access to the system but it appears that the issues lies with trying to set the machine into stand-by mode.

Attempting to researching whether or not Windows XP Embedded actually supports stand-by mode I have been unable to find an answer - hence the question.

Comment: @EEAA Windows XP Embedded is [supported until January 2016](https://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/product-lifecycles.aspx). Users should be planning to migrate now, but I think it's a bit early to say they shouldn't have them at all.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Haha, figures. Well, good luck then, Dale. Honestly this sort of thing seems simple enough to just test, right?